# Como leer correctamente un csv en un DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Esta es mi primera pregunta en esta pagina, espero que la entiendan.
Aqui esta mi problema, yo tengo este csv:

[image: CSV]

Y lo quiero meter a un DataFrame con pandas, pero la primera línea de todas "Consulta de centros..." me esta dando problemas, ya que quiero indexar por los nombres de la segunda fila.
He intentado borrar la primera fila del csv con esto:

```
with open(csv_py,'r') as f:
    with open("listado2.csv",'w') as f1:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

Pero al introducirlo al DataFrame es como si la segunda columna se moviese una posición a la derecha quedando de la siguiente forma.
[image: DataFrame]

También lo he intentado pasando el parámetro skiprow a read_csv pero igual el problema persiste. de la única manera que funciona es borrando manualmente la línea pero es algo que me gustaría automatizar, ¿alguien sabe que puedo hacer? 
Aquí os dejo parte del código:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
descargas = os.environ['USERPROFILE']+'\\Downloads'

csvs = []
for archivo in os.listdir(descargas):
 if archivo.endswith('.csv'):
    csvs.append(archivo)

os.chdir(descargas)
shutil.copy(csvs[-1], cwd)

os.chdir(cwd)

with open(csvs[-1],'r') as f:
    with open("listado2.csv",'w') as f1:
        next(f) # skip header line
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)

df = pd.read_csv('listado2.csv', sep=';', engine='python')
print(df)
```

Muchas Gracias.
EDIT(Enlace al csv original sin modificar):https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J4jx1PKagqpLUlOhd2Gb5WEwfRIP2HG5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tu archivo çsv no tiene la estructura correcta, tengo una posible solución pero necesito comprobarlo, podrías subir tu csv a la nube y colocar un enlace?

Comment: pandas ya lee el archivo, no es necesario volverlo a leer con `open`, en su lugar utiliza `index_col` para indicar que columna será el índice

Comment: Hola Christian si aquí te dejo un enlace al drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J4jx1PKagqpLUlOhd2Gb5WEwfRIP2HG5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ya se que pandas puedes hacer un reindex pero no se si el csv en algún momento cambiara o se le añadirá un nuevo campo.

Comment: un skiprows= 1 en el read_csv() no deberia ser suficiente?

Comment: realice una prueba con el csv dado y pues si, quita la primera linea y lo abre con normalidad sin necesidad de abrirlo antes

Comment: Ya lo intente anki, y no no me dejo mismo resultado que el que muestro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para casos en los que el archivo `csv` este mal formado, es recomendable usar `index_col=False`, esto hará que pandas no tome la primera columna como el índice. EN tu caso pasa esto y pandas al utilizar la primera columna también se lleva con sigo el primer dato que debería de ser el nombre del campo, para evitar eso usamos el parámetro antes mencionado.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv",sep=';', engine='python',skiprows=1,index_col=False)
print(df)
```

utilizamos `skiprows=1` para omitir la primera fila, luego utilizamos `index_col=False` para que los índices no sean la primera columna sino numeros asignados por pandas.

**resultado**

|  | AREA TERRITORIAL | CODIGO CENTRO | ... | FAX | TITULARIDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Madrid-Oeste | 28060816 | ... | 918905994 | P�blico |
| 1 | Madrid-Capital | 28065711 | ... | 915650151 | P�blico |
| 2 | Madrid-Sur | 28077907 | ... | 916085507 | P�blico |
| 3 | Madrid-Norte | 28041354 | ... | 916548684 | P�blico |
| 4 | Madrid-Capital | 28033539 | ... | 913291525 | P�blico |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 656 | Madrid-Capital | 28008806 | ... | 915191424 | Privado |
| 657 | Madrid-Oeste | 28030681 | ... | 916322527 | Privado |
| 658 | Madrid-Capital | 28009677 | ... | - | Privado |
| 659 | Madrid-Sur | 28029445 | ... | 918611356 | Privado |
| 660 | Madrid-Capital | 28076927 | ... | - | Privado |

Comment: Maravilloso Christian, muchísimas gracias. 10 / 10

Comment: el index_col=False fue lo que había obviado xD,

Comment: jeje, igual me diste una pista @AnkiJedi, mi idea era solo usar el `index_col` pero tarde o temprano tenia que usar el `skiprows` c:

Answer (score 0):

Igual no entendí bien tú problema pero creo que es que las cabeceras sean la segunda linea.

**Me responde:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("ColegiosMadrid.csv", sep=';', header=1)
print ( df )
```

```
    AREA TERRITORIAL  CODIGO CENTRO  ...        FAX TITULARIDAD
0       Madrid-Oeste       28060816  ...  918905994     P�blico
1     Madrid-Capital       28065711  ...  915650151     P�blico
2         Madrid-Sur       28077907  ...  916085507     P�blico
3       Madrid-Norte       28041354  ...  916548684     P�blico
4     Madrid-Capital       28033539  ...  913291525     P�blico
..               ...            ...  ...        ...         ...
656   Madrid-Capital       28008806  ...  915191424     Privado
657     Madrid-Oeste       28030681  ...  916322527     Privado
658   Madrid-Capital       28009677  ...          -     Privado
659       Madrid-Sur       28029445  ...  918611356     Privado
660   Madrid-Capital       28076927  ...          -     Privado

[661 rows x 11 columns]
```

Descargué el archivo y lo llamé `ColegiosMadrid.csv` y le añadí que la cabecera empiece en la linea 1 `header=1`

Espero que fuese ese tu problema

Comment: noup, eso dará el mismo resultado que `skiprows`

Comment: probé tu código y no soluciona el problema, las columnas siguen desplazándose a la derecha

Comment: Hola tomy, muchas gracias pero no me ha funcionado, me sigue pasando lo mismo de siempre en el data frame la cabecera se mueve una posición a la derecha mostrando el mismo resultado que en la imagen que aporte en la pregunta.

Comment: En mi pc me muestra el resultado que te envié, sorry

Comment: Me estoy dando cuenta de una diferencia. Para guardar el archivo inicial lo leí con las Libreoffice Latin1 y fue Libreoffice quien creó y guardó el fichero que estoy leyendo